# Is it possible to watch Youtube videos on the Youtube App while multitasking

Tags: youtube, google-apps, multitasking

I currently have Kit Kat 4.4. Is is possible to play a Youtube video in the background or while multitasking like checking email,  use other apps or surf the web on Android? As of right now, I have to have keep the Youtube app open and can't get the video to play in the background while I do other stuff on my phone.

Comment: Official answer: no. The youtube app was changed about 2 years ago to ensure once it wasn't focused on, it would stop, including locking the screen. In actuality: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3447673/how-play-youtube-videos-in-background-on-android/ This may work and there are other work arounds. Supposedly they will improve the feature in Youtube itself according to this article from October: http://venturebeat.com/2013/10/23/youtubes-android-app-to-finally-let-you-play-music-in-the-background/

Comment: This is possible due to some features on custom ROMs (like Paranoid Android's [Halo](https://plus.google.com/107979589566958860409/posts/PZK62GAeJVZ)) and multitasking on some TouchWiz devices; of course, this requires you to completely modify your device. Alternatively, [Floating Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flapps) allows you to have an instance of an app (ie. YouTube, Vimeo, Video Player) floating above other windows and does not require root.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi task option of your phone. Your screen will be split into 2 parts, you can watch Youtube and do other stuff. You can also change the formation of the screen so 90% of the screen is browser/email etc en 10% of screen will be youtube for listening music.

I am pretty sure Android Kitkat can do that – I am doing it right now.

Comment: Two things: First, please don't use txtspeak (write full words) – many of our users are non-native English speakers and already have a hard time without slang. Second: The feature you describe IMHO is not available on all devices, but rather vendor specific – so you should at least mention the device you're using ;)